# Mi banner de admob no se ve, pero el de prueba si

Tags: android, admob

Estoy intentando poner anuncios por primera vez a una de mis apps, cuando lo hago con el id de prueba de admob: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111 el banner se ve perfectamente en el emulador de android studio, por lo cual descarto que haya algún error en mi programa. Pero cuando lo hago con mi id de admob no se ve.

Decir que la cuenta de admob la he creado hoy mismo y nose si hace falta iniciar el banner desde la web de alguna forma o algo.

Mi código es:
En la clase desde donde creo la activity:

```
    AdView mAdView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

//En la activity tengo este código para el banner:

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView 
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_id"
    ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

//En manifest tengo:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
                android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx"
                />

//Y en dependencias:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```

Pd: nose si tiene algo que ver pero la app aún no está publicada en la play store (por si afecta en algo a admob).

Pd2: Parece que simplemente esperando algo más de 24 horas se ha solucionado y ya se ven los anuncios con mi id en android studio. Supongo que admob los debe haber validado de alguna forma.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te invito a leer [ask], te sugiero agregar el código de lo que estas realizando para que la comunidad te pueda apoyar de mejor manera. Realiza el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio, saludos!

Comment: @Elenasys Gracias dicho y hecho, ya está editado. Saludos

Comment: El banner_id que defines en Strings.xml también inicia con ca-app-pub?

Comment: @Elenasys si tiene el formato ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx, donde cada x es un número

Comment: He añadido el código de manifest y dependencias

Comment: Parece que simplemente esperando algo más de 24 horas se ha solucionado y ya se ven los anuncios con mi id en android studio. Supongo que admob los debe haber validado de alguna forma. Saludos y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Si no tienes la app publicada , dificilmente admob hará una impresión en tu app , si funciona en el emulador y te muestra el anuncio de prueba , estás implementando bien los metodos , solo es cuestión de publicarla y esperar a que las solicitudes se vuelvan impresiones